# CloudFormation CodePipeline template is not authorized to preform AssumeRole, why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

for days I have not been able to figure out why one AWS role is not authorized to perform AssumeRole on another. In this case I have a dev-account with AWS CodeCommit on it, and a tools account with CodePipeline. I am trying to allow CodePipeline (in tools) to access CodeCommit (in dev), but am always told that the role in tools is not authorized to do so.

Here is my CloudFormation template to create a role in dev:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: Cross Account Role to Allow Access to CodePipeline in Tools Account
Parameters:
  ToolsAccount:
    Description: AWS AccountNumber for tools account
    Type: Number
Resources:
  Role:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: access-codecommit-in-dev
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS:
                - !Ref ToolsAccount
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: /

  Policy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: !Sub ToolsAcctCodePipelineCodeCommitPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - codecommit:BatchGetRepositories
              - codecommit:Get*
              - codecommit:GitPull
              - codecommit:List*
              - codecommit:CancelUploadArchive
              - codecommit:UploadArchive
              - s3:*
            Resource: "*"
      Roles:
        - !Ref Role
```

Here is the CloudFormation template that creates CodePipeline:

```
Description: "Code pipeline to deploy frontend"

Parameters:
  DevAccount:
    Description: AWS AccountNumber for dev
    Type: Number
  TestAccount:
    Description: AWS AccountNumber for test
    Type: Number

Resources:
  BuildProjectRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: codebuild-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - codebuild.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole

  BuildProjectPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: codebuild-policy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - s3:PutObject
              - s3:GetBucketPolicy
              - s3:GetObject
              - s3:ListBucket
            Resource:
              - "bucketNameHere"
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - logs:CreateLogGroup
              - logs:CreateLogStream
              - logs:PutLogEvents
            Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*
      Roles:
        - !Ref BuildProjectRole

  PipeLineRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: codepipeline-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - codepipeline.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole

  PipelinePolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: codepipeline-policy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - codepipeline:*
              - iam:ListRoles
              - cloudformation:Describe*
              - cloudFormation:List*
              - codecommit:List*
              - codecommit:Get*
              - codecommit:GitPull
              - codecommit:UploadArchive
              - codecommit:CancelUploadArchive
              - codebuild:BatchGetBuilds
              - codebuild:StartBuild
              - cloudformation:CreateStack
              - cloudformation:DeleteStack
              - cloudformation:DescribeStacks
              - cloudformation:UpdateStack
              - cloudformation:CreateChangeSet
              - cloudformation:DeleteChangeSet
              - cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet
              - cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet
              - cloudformation:SetStackPolicy
              - cloudformation:ValidateTemplate
              - iam:PassRole
              - s3:ListAllMyBuckets
              - s3:GetBucketLocation
            Resource:
              - "*"
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - s3:PutObject
              - s3:GetBucketPolicy
              - s3:GetObject
              - s3:ListBucket
            Resource:
              - "bucketName"
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
            Resource:
              - !Sub arn:aws:iam::${DevAccount}:role/crossaccount-codecommit-access

      Roles:
        - !Ref PipeLineRole

  FrontEndPipeline:
    Type: "AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline"
    Properties:
      ArtifactStore:
        Type: "S3"
        Location: "bucketName"
      Name: "frontend-deploy"
      RoleArn: !GetAtt PipeLineRole.Arn
      Stages:
        - Name: "Code-Fetch"
          Actions:
            - Name: "stage-source"
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Source
                Owner: AWS
                Provider: CodeCommit
                Version: 1
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceCode
              Configuration:
                PollForSourceChanges: true
                BranchName: develop
                RepositoryName: "nameHere"
              RunOrder: 1
              RoleArn: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${DevAccount}:role/crossaccount-codecommit-access

        - Name: Build
          Actions:
            - Name: "Build-Source"
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Build
                Owner: AWS
                Version: "1"
                Provider: CodeBuild
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: SourceCode
              OutputArtifacts:
                - Name: DeployOutput
              Configuration:
                ProjectName: "CodeBuild"
              RunOrder: 1
        - Name: Deploy
          Actions:
            - Name: deploy
              ActionTypeId:
                Category: Deploy
                Owner: AWS
                Version: "1"
                Provider: S3
              InputArtifacts:
                - Name: DeployOutput
              Configuration:
                BucketName: "bucketNameHere"
                Extract: true
                #RoleArn: !Sub arn:aws:iam::${TestAccount}:role/cloudformationdeployer-role

  CodeBuildProject:
    Type: AWS::CodeBuild::Project
    Properties:
      Name: "CodeBuild"
      ServiceRole: !GetAtt BuildProjectRole.Arn
      Artifacts:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
      Environment:
        ComputeType: BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL
        Type: LINUX_CONTAINER
        Image: node:13
      Source:
        Type: CODEPIPELINE
```

What could possibly be generating this error:

```
arn:aws:iam::{ToolsAccount}:role/projectName-codepipeline-role is not authorized to perform AssumeRole on role arn:aws:iam::{DevAcciybt}:role/access-codecommit-in-dev (Service: AWSCodePipeline; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidStructureException; Request ID: (ID here))
```

Comment: I've successfully been able to use the instructions from [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/aws-building-a-secure-cross-account-continuous-delivery-pipeline/) blog post to create the cross-account pipeline. Are using it as your template?

Answer (score 0):

Does the role 
arn:aws:iam::{ToolsAccount}:role/projectName-codepipeline-role  have permission to assume the role in dev account something like below:

{
"Sid": "AssumeCrossAccountRole"
"Effect": "Allow",
"Actions": "sts:AssumeRole",
"Resource": "ARN of dev account role"
}

else
Try out with passing ARN arn:aws:iam::{ToolsAccount}:role/projectName-codepipeline-role in the AWS principal instead of account number for the role which you are creating in dev account